# pulldom вернуть xml по xpath запросу

Tags: python, xml, xpath

Всем добрый вечер!
Подскажите, как можно вернуть xml документ, с открывающими и закрывающими тегами с использованием модуля pulldom и xpath:
XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<cars>
  <car>
    <model>Audi</model>
    <models>
        <name>a6</name>
        <name>a7</name>
        <name>a8</name>
    </models>
  </car>
</cars>
```

Python:

```
import xml.dom.pulldom as pulldom
import xpath

events = pulldom.parse('test.xml')
for event, node in events:
    if event == 'START_ELEMENT' and node.tagName=='car':
        events.expandNode(node)
        models = xpath.findvalues('models/name', node)
        print(models)
```

То есть должно вернуться:

```
<name>a6</name>
<name>a7</name>
<name>a8</name>
```

Comment: Зачем вам именно pulldom? Чтобы перебрать все `<name>` элементы в документе, используя [ElementTree API: `root.iter('name')`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html)

Comment: Мне просто надо использовать именно pull parser

Comment: Что  вы пытаетесь достичь, используя "pull parser" при чтении из локального файла? Попробуйте iterparse(), если по частям хотите файл читать. [Пример кода](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26435241/4279).

Comment: Возможно это то что мне нужно, но вопрос как применить в таком случае xpath и получить xml?

Comment: для вашего примера достаточно вызывать `getelements('test.xml', 'name')` или `for car in getelements('test.xml', 'car'): print(car.find(xpath_expression))` если не `<name>`, а  что-то другое хотите найти.

Comment: В xpath_expresses я могу свое выражение написать?